# Keep CPU busy at certain percent (to prevent CPU buzzing frequency noises)

Tags: linux, scripting, cpu

On `Dell Inspiron 7559` there is electric buzzing from beneath the keyboard that changes frequency when I touch the touchpad.

However, if the CPU is busy I hear no buzzing as the frequency gets out of my hearing range.

I was hoping to run a script to keep CPU busy enough and keep the laptop silent, something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
recursiveDelay(){ sleep 0.001; recursiveDelay;}
recursiveDelay
```

But it gradually get's the CPU percent higher and higher.

How could I keep it at a certain percent?

Comment: Haha, this is a horrible hack. Figure out the problem instead. Almost as bad as [xkcd: Workflow](https://xkcd.com/1172/).

Comment: I agree, but I can't and I can't change the hardware, so I just want to hack it.

Comment: Have you considered opening the machine up and checking what makes it buzz? You seem to be looking for a software solution to a mechanical problem. I'm guessing that cleaning the fan will fix this.

Comment: The fan has nothing to do with this and I cannot fix it mechanically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's probably happening is that the CPU goes into a more aggressive power-save mode. This causes the internal switch-mode voltage regulators to go into a pulse-skipping mode, moving the switching frequency down to the audible range. The noise comes from the inductors and capacitors, both being slightly microphonic (which also works in reverse; the emit sound)

It's a lousy design, but you're stuck with it.

The "best" way to solve it is to go into BIOS and configure your CPU for a less aggressive throttling. This would prevent all the fancy power saving modes to kick in, so you don't have to mess with these tasks.

Another way is to run a *useful* task, for example [SETI@Home](http://setiathome.ssl.berkeley.edu/) or some other thing you might want to do. I *think* SETI@Home can set a CPU limit percentage, but if not, you may be able to use the `cpulimit` linux command.

The least interesting way is to just burn up cycles with one of the stress-test utilities. techraf already suggested stress-ng, and there are a few other similar utilities.

If you can not find a utility with a fine-grained enough throttle, I whipped up this perl one-liner for you. The throttling can be tweaked. I use perl because that's what I know. Insert your favourite programming language.

`perl -MTime::HiRes=sleep -e 'sleep 0.0001 while 1'`

Changing the 0.0001 part will make it use more or less CPU.

Comment: I've read about power-saving modes and unfortunatelly my BIOS has no options for it. I have `Dell Inspiron 7559`. Also, I thought about the mentioned tasks as I have it running when my PC is idle, but I want it to be simple and of constant complexity.

Comment: @Radivarig I tried a small perl script that hopefully does what you want with enough granularity. Works fine on my machine at least.

Comment: Perfect! The perl script takes 1% of CPU and removes the buzzing completely. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

On Debian or Ubuntu install [stress-ng](http://smackerelofopinion.blogspot.jp/2014/06/stress-ng-updated-system-stress-test.html) with `apt-get install stress-ng`.

Then run:

```
stress-ng -c 1 -l 50
```

playing with `-c` (number of CPUs) and `-l` (percentage load) parameters.

---

For Fedora/RedHat/CentOS it seems you have to compile it (source repository is [here](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~cking/tarballs/stress-ng/)) with the following procedure:

```
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~cking/tarballs/stress-ng/stress-ng-0.05.25.tar.gz
tar zxvf stress-ng-0.05.25.tar.gz
cd stress-ng-0.05.25/
make
./stress-ng -c 2 -l 50
```

Comment: This keeps the CPU around given percentage based on `top`, but it seems it doesn't keep it busy consistently as I get a periodic on/off noise.

Comment: Maybe you need to run two instances in counterphase ;)